# C# context.Response.OutputStream.Write Hebrew characters

Tags: c#

I'm trying to export a report to csv using this code:

```
byte[] csvBytes = AttachmentFileAgent.GetAttachmentFilesCSVBytes(context.Request["appCode"], performingPerson);
context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=ApplicationReport_" + context.Request["appCode"] + ".csv");
context.Response.ContentType = "text/csv;charset=utf-8";
context.Response.Charset = "utf-8";
context.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
context.Response.OutputStream.Write(csvBytes, 0, csvBytes.Length);
```

But the Hebrew content goes out in gibberish (׳›׳¢׳›׳’׳¢׳›׳’׳›׳¢).
I tryied ising all kinds on encoding (UTF8, Unicode, ASCII) but nothing works...

Comment: How does `GetAttachmentFilesCSVBytes` convert the data to bytes?

Comment: try : charset=windows-1255.  See followiing webpage : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b63d7724-6dca-4cf4-9665-fad17e809d0e/why-im-getting-gibberish-when-trying-to-parse-hebrew-text-from-a-string-?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: This is most likely some encoding issue. I would guess that `GetAttachmentFilesCSVBytes` assumes output in a specific coding, which might not be `UTF-8`, but the local setting of the machine (which might be `windows-1255` for Hebrew).

Comment: `GetAttachmentFilesCSVBytes` returns like this: `return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(...);`

Comment: I even tryied windows-1255 like this `context.Response.ContentType = "text/csv;charset=Windows-1255";
                    context.Response.Charset = "Windows-1255";
                    context.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1255");` and it didn't work

Comment: Use the debugger to look at `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(csvBytes)`. Is the string intact or broken? What does that tell you?

Comment: I used `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(csvBytes)` and the string returns ok, with Hebrew.

Comment: What does that tell you about where the problem lies? Don't just ignore questions that I ask.

Comment: It brings me back to question I've asked at the begining... seems like the problem lies in the code I've posted

Comment: Or, in the client that you use to look at the file. The bytes that you write are correct. Therefore, the client must be misinterpreting the bytes.

Comment: How is this possible if I can read Hebrew in my computer ?

Answer (score 1):

Your changes to `context.Response.ContentEncoding` sets the encoding on the `TextWriter` used by `context.Response.Output`

When using `context.Response.OutputStream` you need to set the UTF-8 encoding used in your `GetAttachmentFilesCSVBytes`function.

Also see [ASP.NET: Will Saving an XmlDocument to the Response.OutputStream honor the encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546994/asp-net-will-saving-an-xmldocument-to-the-response-outputstream-honor-the-encod)