# Write Serialized XML to String and Display in Browser

Tags: asp.net, serialization, xml-serialization, rijndaelmanaged

I have a serialized object which needs to be sent as an encrypted XML string. I am able to save the serialized object to a well-formed XML file, but this is not what I want. I have already got Rijndael encrypt/decrypt working for a sample string.

```
Person person = new Person("Irish", "Chieftain");
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person));

// Write serialized XML to file
System.Guid guid = System.Guid.NewGuid();
StreamWriter streamWriter 
    = new StreamWriter(@"C:\application" + "_" + guid.ToString() + ".xml")
xmlSerializer.Serialize(streamWriter.BaseStream, person);
```

**I want to be able to display the XML string in the browser**, before encryption, to test that the correct encrypted string is being sent to the decrypt method on the other machine.

I have been beating on this for a week and have looked to other answers on SO, such as:
[How to return XML in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543319/how-to-return-xml-in-asp-net)

Can anyone show me the correct syntax to display the generated XML as a string in the browser?

**[UPDATE]**
Here is what I'm trying to render the XML:

```
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
XmlTextWriter xmlWriter2 = new XmlTextWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8); 
xmlWriter2.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlWriter2, person);
memoryStream = (MemoryStream) xmlWriter2.BaseStream;
UTF8Encoding encoding2 = new UTF8Encoding();
stringData = encoding2.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
Response.Write(stringData);
```

**[UPDATE 2]**

If I remove the "text/xml" content type, I get the following when I view source (is this correct?):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Person xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <FirstName>Irish</FirstName>
  <SecondName>Chieftain</SecondName>
</Person>
```

**[Update 3]**

Working version:

```
            #region Display original string
            // Write serialized XML to a string - Display purposes.
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            XmlTextWriter xmlWriter2 
                = new XmlTextWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8);
            xmlWriter2.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlWriter2, person);
            memoryStream = (MemoryStream) xmlWriter2.BaseStream;
            UTF8Encoding encoding2 = new UTF8Encoding();
            stringData = encoding2.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());

            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.Cache.SetAllowResponseInBrowserHistory(true);
            Response.Write(stringData);
            Response.End();
            #endregion
```

Comment: I pasted your xml into a text file, changed it from .txt to .xml and opened it in IE. no problems, it showed the tree view and all was good. I loaded it in chrome and all it displayed was the text "Irish Chiegtain"

Comment: Thanks Muad'Dib, marking as answer :-)

Comment: I'm missing something here: where does encryption fit in?  Encrypted XML wouldn't qualify as XML...

Comment: I'm encrypting the above XML and decrypting it on the receiving machine. I wanted to be sure that the correct XML was being sent out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is quite likely that you need to set the [ContentType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.contenttype.aspx) on your Response object. This corresponds to the MIME type.  for xml it should be `text/xml`

Comment: When I added the Content Type, I got: "XML Parsing Error: junk after document element"

Comment: sounds like malformed xml. I would put a breakpoint at your Response.Write and look at the stringData.  Make sure it has a leading <xml> tag

Comment: I can see what appears to be correct XML, but only when I remove the Content Type? See Update 2 above.

Comment: Your XML looks right.  What browser are you viewing it in? chrome will only display the text, not the tags in a "tree view" manner.

Comment: Firefox 3.6, IE9 and Chrome all displaying only the text, which is what confused me but I'm still curious why the content type gives that error "junk" message?

Comment: yea, that IS bizarre. could be unprintable characters in the string. could be other parts of the header disagree with your ContentType

Comment: I changed order of execution in my code and IE9 and Firefox now display the XML when Content Type is set to "text\xml" :)

Comment: I was going to say that you need to change headers *before* a `Flush`.

Answer (score 0):

HtmlEncoding the XML string will also resolve the issue.

Response.Write(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(stringData ));