# Writing xml file to web service

Tags: vb.net

I am able to read the xml file into dataset. Currently it is printing in a string format. Is it possible to print in xml format from web method call. I want to publish through dataset.writexml

```
Public Function HelloWorld() As String
    Dim dsProducts As New DataSet()
    Dim swriter As New IO.StringWriter

    dsProducts.ReadXml(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "\Product.xml").ToString()
    dsProducts.WriteXml(swriter)

    Return swriter.ToString()
End Function
```

Is it possible with XMLTextWriter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an `XMLDocument` object and call `LoadXML(yourXMLString)`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml

This will load that string into that object and from there, you can save the XML to a file. Is that what you're looking for?

**EDIT:**

The `DataSet` class has a `GetXML()` method which returns the XML String that you can pass to your webservice. Is that what your webservice is expecting? An XML string?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.getxml

Comment: On click of HelloWorld and invoke, it should display the data in xml format so that i can read it from other service

Comment: I'm confused. Do you want to display the XML to the user onscreen?

Comment: It is not for onscreen. But other service needs to consume this webservice in the form of xml.

Comment: Well, you said "display". See my edit. I think I know what you want, now.

Comment: Hi Yatrix, I just need to return XML from HelloWorld in proper format so that i can read it from other dataset in other WebService. The string xml cannot be read directly from dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Xdoc.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) Your method can return an XML document instead of a string. Also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543319/how-to-return-xml-in-asp-net) will probably help you reach your solution.

Comment: Here I don't want to go with Response object. Just a XMLTextWriter