# why i lose xml header on asp.net web service

Tags: xml, web-services

I have a web service method and I convert to xml for viewing asp page my xml converter method:

```
        SqlDataAdapter MyDataAdapter;
        MyDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(com.CommandText, SqlConnection);
        DataSet dsCategories = new DataSet();
        MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 1000;

        MyDataAdapter.Fill(dsCategories, "Category");
        dsCategories.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("Category.xml"));  

        System.IO.StringWriter writer = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        dsCategories.WriteXml(writer, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
        string xmlFromDataTable = writer.ToString();
        response.Write(xmlFromDataTable);
        response.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-16";
```

The error is

> on line 1846 at column 19: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document

The XML does not have the XML Declaration header. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that there is some other stuff being written to the page which precedes your XML.

Perhaps if you try to following (add response.Clear()):

```
string xmlFromDataTable = writer.ToString();
response.Clear();
response.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-16";
response.Write(xmlFromDataTable);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.clear.aspx

Comment: thanks but it is no working i think, i find the error because of '&' sign. Because my data include more than '&' sign. How to fix it?

Comment: The ampersand you'd need to esacpe, but if your XML file is already well-formed then it should be escaped already.  Can you just open the XML file on your filesystem with IE without any errors/warnings?  This here pretty much covers anything that could go wrong.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/543319/how-to-return-xml-in-asp-net

Comment: XML file opened truely i dont understand the error but i approved another way, i use list for getting the data thanks for helping