# Response.Write() vs Response.Outputstream()

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, xml-parsing

I'm getting some strange behavoir with my xml-ouput.

I'm filling my xml using a Stringwriter and a xmltextwriter.

```
Using textw As New IO.StringWriter
    Using xmlw As New System.Xml.XmlTextWriter(textw)
    ....
    End Using
```

However when outputting the data. i'm getting two different results for the same ('in my eyes') methodoligy. In both situations tw will contain my xml

**Non working version: (in IE)**

```
Response.Clear()
Response.Write(textw.ToString)
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
Response.ContentType = "text/xml"
Response.End()
```

Errormessage is telling there is an error in the contents of my xml.

**working version: (in IE)**

```
Response.Clear()
Dim xmlDoc As New XmlDocument
xmlDoc.LoadXml(textw.ToString)
xmlDoc.Save(Response.OutputStream)
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
Response.ContentType = "text/xml"
Response.End()
```

**Question:** What is the difference between `Response.write` and `Response.Outputstream`?

**Note:** Both method appear to be working in firefox & chrome. The xml is valid as its already in use at the moment (using the working version).

Comment: More detailed answer on the same topic is given here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2163400

Comment: Brings up good results, but i still don't get when i should be using Response.Write or Response.Output(stream)

Comment: The answer suggested by @Soham actually details that you shouldn't use either (and the reasons why). Instead you should be using Response.Output.

Comment: I can only deduct from the post that Reponse.Output is the way to follow while outputting xml. My questions was more along the lines of "When should I opt to use Response.Write". Is there a special reason for its existance?

Comment: When doing <% = %> in the aspx, it like calling Response.Write(). Maybe it just depends on if you happen to have a string or a stream. And for using Output or OutputStream it all depends on what type of stream you have.

Comment: @svranken Response.Write adds string data to the Response buffer. It usually used to write text & if possible, should avoid all concatenations. See this link for benchmarks of different usage scenarios: http://www.dotnetperls.com/response-write